# Error on programmatically adding servicerefrence

Tags: c#, web-services, plugins, webservice-client, service-reference

I am making a plugin for rhinoceros with C# and WPF, and this application needed a webservice to contact with database, so I made webservice and added it to the application as a servicereference.

[image]
although it works fine outside of rhino, when I load plugin inside rhino it came with this error:

[image]

So, in the following I decided to add my servicereference programmatically in order to make my application recognize it when my main window is loading and I came up with this code:

```
        public static string WS_Host = "https://localhost:44309/Services/";
        public static BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        SR_Users.UsersSoapClient sr_users = new UsersSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(WS_Host + "Users.asmx"));
```

I placed this code in my class area, and now the problem is when I add binding and endpoint to the UsersSoapClient, it gives me this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid, expected 'http':

[image]

in rhino or out of it, I have searched and found nothing, can you help solve it please?

I searched and tried every possible way I guessed might fix it.